# Using a different doctrine.yaml file in dev and prod with Symfony4

Tags: database, symfony4

In a symfony4 project, I want to use a sqlite database in local development and a mariadb instance or production. In the structure, I see there is the main `doctrine.yaml` in `config/packages`.

Since sqlite file location congifured with `path:` and mariadb/mysql  finds the connection string via `url:`, can I move the doctrine.yaml file to `/dev/` and add the `dbal:` to `/prod/doctrine.yaml`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because of these lines in your `src/Kernel.php`, Symfony will load first your global packages, and next your per-environment packages

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader)
{
     $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

    $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
}
```